# How can I add an entry for my new Ubuntu installation to GRUB on a dual boot system?

Tags: 14.04, bootloader

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on a harddisk. Now I have also installed Ubuntu 14.04, but it's not showing up in the bootloader, so I can only access Windows and Ubuntu 12.04. How do I add Ubuntu 14.04?

This is my result.txt from the bootinfoscript:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grldr /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /grldr

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda3 
                       and looks at sector 193770792 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       in partition 112 for .
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   136,918,100   136,711,253   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         176,334,848   234,436,607    58,101,760  83 Linux
/dev/sda4         136,919,038   176,334,847    39,415,810   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         136,919,040   172,161,023    35,241,984  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         172,163,072   176,334,847     4,171,776  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        B864A6BA64A67B30                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        8896E94A96E93978                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        797bf0ed-1b42-4a0d-adb3-77b612e3cae0   ext4       
/dev/sda5        4561699f-00dd-4385-9d41-a7f3b35c9c8d   ext4       
/dev/sda6        ae23d389-a2a5-4bd4-847f-9a915efb9d5c   swap       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /media/System Reserved   fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2        /media/8896E94A96E93978  fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3        /media/797bf0ed-1b42-4a0d-adb3-77b612e3cae0 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sda5        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


========================== sda1/grldr embedded menu: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=========================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and if it does not work run the Summary Report and post the link to the summary report. The summary report uses a newer fork of bootinfoscript and adds even more info which is too large to directly post. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu14 did the install not "see" the existing 2 OSs? Are you using legacy BIOS boot or UEFI?

Answer (score -1):

os-prober i believe only works with mounted partitions. So you first need to mount the other Ubuntu install somewhere then run update-grub.

Comment: This is true if non-standard formats. For example if you have a standard install that does not have the lvm2 driver, you have to add that and then mount your LVM partition(s) for os-prober to find them.  But most cases not required.